# denied: requested access to the resource is denied -- Jenkins Console log

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-build

Docker Toolbox and Jenkins installed on Window 10

I am stuck in pushing docker image from Jenkins to docker hub. I created a freestyle Jenkins project where i built maven project and then try to create docker image and push it to docker hub. I am stuck at last step.

When I try to push image from docker-cli it works. But when I do this using Jenkins, it gets stuck. I have added docker credentials in credential manager, even logged in to docker-hub account in docker cli, but I am not able to resolve this. Any idea where I am going wrong?

**Jenkins Console Log**

```
Successfully built 6dcaf50d6cff
Successfully tagged divyankgupta/docker-jenkins-integration-sample:11jan
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-
Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have 
‘-rwxr-xr-x’ permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
[jenkins-docker-integration] $ C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\bin\docker tag 6dcaf50d6cff divyankgupta/docker-jenkins-integration-sample:latest
[jenkins-docker-integration] $ C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\bin\docker inspect 6dcaf50d6cff
[jenkins-docker-integration] $ C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\bin\docker push divyankgupta/docker-jenkins-integration-sample:11jan
The push refers to repository [docker.io/divyankgupta/docker-jenkins-integration-
sample]
6173fc90427a: Preparing
7d0784c2c563: Preparing
715d0a3d2cc2: Preparing
155d997ed77c: Preparing
88cfc2fcd059: Preparing
760e8d95cf58: Preparing
7cc1c2d7e744: Preparing
8c02234b8605: Preparing
760e8d95cf58: Waiting
7cc1c2d7e744: Waiting
8c02234b8605: Waiting
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
Build step ‘Docker Build and Publish’ marked build as failure

Finished: FAILURE*
```

[image: Jenkins Console Log]